# Add a File to a JList using a button

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to add (multiple) files to a JList using a button. I can open the file chooser, but the files are not saving in the JList. Can someone please help me? This is what I have so far:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {

    DefaultListModel mod = new DefaultListModel();
    
    JList jList1 = new JList();
    int f = jList1.getModel().getSize();
    mod.add(f, fc.getSelectedFile());
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `JList jList1 = new JList();
    int f = jList1.getModel().getSize();` Of course `f` will always be 0 here, you did check the value, right?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the JList actually has a model.

Declare the model as **String** type so not to be using a **Raw Types**.

Before the file name is added to the JList, make sure it isn't already there.

Use the **addElement()** method instead of the **add()** method:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Select a file from JFileChooser
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (result != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // If a file was not selected then get outta here
        return;
    }

    // Place the selected file name into a String variable.
    String fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();

    // Make sure the JList contains a model (it is possible not to have)
    DefaultListModel<String> mod;
    try {
        // If this passes then the current model is 
        // acquired from the JList.
        mod = (DefaultListModel<String>) jList1.getModel();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // JList didn't have a model so, we supply one,
        jList1.setModel(new DefaultListModel<>());
        // then we aqcuire that model
        mod = (DefaultListModel<String>) jList1.getModel();
    }

    // Make sure the selected file is not already 
    // contained within the list.  
    boolean alreadyHave = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mod.getSize(); i++) {
        if (mod.getElementAt(i).equals(fileName)) {
            alreadyHave = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If not already in List then add the file name.
    if (!alreadyHave) {
        mod.addElement(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still there are no files showing up in the jList1 every time I try to add one?

Comment: Do you get **any errors**? Are you in fact trying to add to a **JList**? What **IDE and Java version** are you using? Is your particular JList you want to add files to actually named **jList1**? Is **jList1** contained within the same class as the **jButton1ActionPerformed()** event? If your JList already contains elements (like: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc) then go into the model through your Properties pane and delete them reset to default